# Azure cosmosdb migration tool multiple collections

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how / if it's possible to define multiple collections, with different collection names such as "Hello" "There" "General",  as the source for cosmosdb migration tool?

I know it's possible if the collections names were numbered, e.g. Hello1 , Hello2, Hello3 etc.

The target appears to have the option to add multiples but source does not.

Link to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLBulkTarget

[image: Source]

[image: Target]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the statement in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSource), you could find the answer.

> To import from a single Azure Cosmos container, enter the name of the
>   collection to import data from. To import from more than one Azure
>   Cosmos container, provide a regular expression to match one or more
>   collection names (for example, collection01 | collection02 |
>   collection03). You may optionally specify, or provide a file for, a
>   query to both filter and shape the data that you're importing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was adding spaces in-between when I tried that so it was failing.